# When embed one application into Qt application, how to get the mouseMoveEvent and embed windows size

Tags: c++, qt

I use a QX11EmbedContainer to embed a application: spicec(it based on X11).
just like follows:

```
QX11EmbedContainer spicec;
spicec.embedClient(winId);
spicec.setMouseTracking(true);
spicec.show();
```

I have some unresolved questions:

1. I reimplemented mouseMoveEvent, but it does not work (the parent widget set setMouseTracking(true) too);
   So how can I get the mouse move event from QX11EmbedContainer?
   Or is there any way can get mouse move event, even the mouse is not in a Qt windows (global mouse move event)?
2. Since the embeded windows have its own size, is there any way get the original size of the the embeded windows? Because I want adjust my qt application to show its full content.

The environment is Ubuntu 14.04 and Qt 4.8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QXT library`,it has a function named `windowGeometry`,the function param is the `WID.or` you can use `Xlib`,function `XGetWindowAttributes` can also work.